# Using MATCH in a One-To-Many Situation

Tags: excel

I have two lists of cities, with their zip codes and states.  One list of dubious quality and the other is definitely correct. I'm trying to look for instances where the dubious list is incorrect.

Any given city may have multiple zip codes associated with it.

I'm attempting to use an index match to accomplish this.  However, Excel's match function doesn't seem to be apply to one-to-many relationships like this. It finds the first zip code associated with a city and then stops.

Is there a better way to perform matches in this situation?

Comment: Do you have enough info. for a [multiple criteria Index/Match](http://spreadsheeto.com/index-match/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out a (fairly easy) solution to this: concatenate the two fields and then match.

Column A included city names and column B was zip codes. So I created a new column C with the formula:

```
=Concatenate(A1, "-", B1)
```

I did this both for the dubious data and the clean data.

From here it was easy to match the concatenated data.

Answer (score 1):

This approach will both display the codes and tell you which rows have the data.  With data like:

[image]

In **D1** enter the city name *Springfield*.
In **D2** enter:

```
=MATCH($D$1,A:A,0)
```

In **D3** enter:

```
=MATCH($D$1,INDEX(A:A,D2+1):INDEX(A:A,9999),0)+D2
```

and copy down until you get an error.  Column **D** identifies the *Springfield* rows.  In **E2** enter:

```
=INDEX(B:B,D2)
```

and copy down to display the codes.

[image]

The approach avoids using array formulas and avoids using *INDIRECT()*.